# Add X days to a typed in date

Tags: javascript, html, date, parsing

I have some JavaScript code that adds 10 days to the date typed into a text box and prints it into another text box, except that instead of updating the month, it just sets the day to 31+, which is obviously a problem.

This is the text box:

**Job Completion Date:**

```
<input type="date" name="completion_date" onblur="autofill_date_1(this.value)">
```

I have a second text box that is supposed to be updated when the text box is clicked out of:

**Report Due Date:**

```
<input type="text" name="due_date" id="autofill_1" readonly>
```

This is the JavaScript code that updates the day, except it does not update the month if the day exceeds the last day of the month:

```
function autofill_date_1(formDate) {
      var interval = 10;
      var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));
      var month = startDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = startDate.getUTCDate();
      var year = startDate.getUTCFullYear();
      var expDate = month + "-" + (day + interval) + "-" + year;
      new_text = document.getElementById("autofill_1");
      new_text.value = newDate;
};
```

I see why this has the problem that it does but I don't have any experience working with dates.  There are a lot of answers already about a similar issue but none of them are helping with the way I am trying.  What would be the best way to fix this issue, maybe a completely different way altogether?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as such and not just edit your question name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of some simple date arithmetic which should be enough to get you going:

```js
var date1 = new Date("10/Dec/2015 20:30:00");

var daysToAdd = 30;
date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + daysToAdd)

document.write(date1.getDate() + "/" + (date1.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date1.getFullYear());
```

Comment: When I run this, I get way too much information, I would just like the day, month, and year.  is there a way to just get that information out of that?

Comment: @Jozzie93 Fixed a minor bug and improved code. Please mark as answered if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

```
function autofill_date_1(formDate){
    var interval = 10;
    var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));
    // Assuming the above date parses well:
    var expDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + interval * 86400000); 
    var month = expDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var day = expDate.getUTCDate();
    var year = expDate.getUTCFullYear();
    var expDate = ('0' + month).substr(-2) + "-" + ('0' + day).substr(-2) + "-" + year;
    new_text = document.getElementById("autofill_1");
    new_text.value = expDate;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!! This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You're welcome, if you consider your question resolved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here is a very simple and elegant solution. The comments in the code should make it clear, but you might want to read up on the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and its methods to fully understand it. You can test the snippet at the bottom of this post :)

```js
var dueDate = document.getElementById('due-date'),
    repDate = document.getElementById('report-date');

dueDate.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  var repDateObj= new Date(this.value),
      nrOfDays  = 10; // nr. of days to report in second input
  
  repDateObj.setDate(repDateObj.getDate()+nrOfDays);

  // [].join('-') is the same as doing item1 + '-' + item2 + '-' etc...
  repDate.value = [
    repDateObj.getFullYear(),
    // if the month/ date are < 10, add a leading 0 so the format is compatible with 
    // the format expected by date inputs (yyyy-mm-dd)
    // add +1 to months because they start at 0=January
    (repDateObj.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') + (repDateObj.getMonth() + 1),
    (repDateObj.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + repDateObj.getDate()
  ].join('-');
  
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="due-date">
<input type="date" id="report-date" disabled>
```